# Generating a string literal from text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<script>
function printStringLiteral(theInput) {
    document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(theInput.value)
}
</script>
<body>
<p>Text to modify:<p>
<input type="text" id = "textInput">

<a onclick="printStringLiteral(document.getElementById('textInput'));" href="javascript:void(0);">Get string literal</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm [trying to create a simple web page](http://jsbin.com/osayan/2) that accepts text as input and returns a string literal, but this web page doesn't display the string literal correctly after it has been generated. I entered `<p>"Hi!"</p>` as input, but `"\"Hi!\"`
 was displayed as output, instead of the correctly formatted string literal. What will I need to do here in order to get the string to display properly?

Comment: What is the result you're expecting? You've converted your string to JSON, hence the escaped quotes, then added it to the document's `innerHTML`, which will interpret the `<p>` tags rather than displaying them. I think the browser is doing correctly what you've asked, but not what you expect

Comment: Don't `JSON.stringify` anything that isn't an array or object. The result is just a JSON string (I'm not sure if that result is guaranteed; that's just what V8 seems to return), but not a valid JSON text, so it can be ignored by JSON parsers.

Comment: -1 for irrelevant whining about downvotes in your question.

Comment: @Paulpro A string literal _is_ valid JSON. Any implementation abiding to the JavaScript language specification _MUST_ return a valid JSON string as defined in the JSON Spec (At least if it's a valid EcmaScript 5 run time). (It's all in http://json.org/ by the way :)).

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It's a valid JSON string, but not a valid JSON text. I'm not sure about the ECMAScript specification, but to conform to Douglas Crockford's RFC a JSON text much start with `[` or `{`. That's not made very clear on json.org .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting the innerHTML, set the text

```
function printStringLiteral(theInput) {
    document.body.textContent += JSON.stringify(theInput.value)
}
```

If you need to support IE8- you need to set `innerText` too